# How to make apache skip specific stdout lines when executing cgi or stop shared library from printing to stdout

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

My apache server executes a cgi bin and reads the lines outputted to stdout. The thing is, every time the cgi-bin is executed some lines due to the API dynamic library loading are present. Apache can't distinguish now those 3 lines from HTTP requests to initiate my streaming.
There is a way to make apache skip the lines that are keeping it from working or to stop the shared libraries from printing its loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site is doing fewer than a couple of requests per second, you can use a simple hack by wrapping your CGI with a shell script that will filter out the problem lines:

-- put the code below in your new cgi script and make sure to `chmod +x`
-- test by running it manually in the shell --

```
#! /bin/bash
/path/to/old-cgi | egrep -v troublestring1\|troublestring2\|troublestring3
```

You must make sure that the trouble strings are unique enough to never legitimately appear in your real output. If you you cannot find such strings, you may need a more sophisticated parsing script in place of `egrep` filter.

Comment: Thank you, it does helped me but it did not solved my problem as i expected.